# Can you override the cache key for a single endpoint in RTK Query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In our API, we unfortunately have a ridiculous endpoint which requires a huge data object to be sent to it; something like:

```
const requestData: RidiculousEndpointRequestData = {
  property1: ...,
  property2: ...,
  // ----- 8< -----
  property100: ...
}
```

But in actual fact, the only properties that the API actually cares about are (say) `property1` and `property2`. So, for this endpoint, it would make more sense if we could make our cache key:

```
endpointName(property1='abc',property2='def')
```

Ideally, it would be good to fix the API so that it actually only required us to pass these two parameters, but unfortunately this option is not available to us.

I know that RTK Query lets us override the cache key serializer for *all* endpoints using the [serializeQueryArgs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#serializequeryargs) parameter; so we *could* do something like this:

```
const serializeQueryArgs = (args) => {
  const { endpointName, queryArgs } = args;
  if (endpointName === 'ridiculousEndpoint') {
    return `${endpointName}(property1=${args.property1},property2=${args.property2})`;
  }

  // I can't do this because defaultSerializeQueryArgs isn't exported :'(
  return defaultSerializeQueryArgs(args);
};

export const dumbApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'our-dumb-api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'some-value' }),
  serializeQueryArgs,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    sensibleEndpoint: build.query<SensibleEndpointResponse, void>({
      // ...
    }),
    ridiculousEndpoint: build.query<RidiculousEndpointResponse, RidiculousEndpointRequestData>({
      // ...
    })
  }),
```

However this is less than ideal for a few reason - not the least of which is that the default serializer (which works fine for all our *other* endpoints) is not exported from RTK Query.

Another option we thought of was to split the API into *two* APIs, one that has our custom serializer, and one that doesn't - but this seems like overkill and it feels like it goes against the design principles of RTK Query.

Is there a better way to customize the cache keys for a single endpoint?

Comment: If all those other arguments don't matter, why do you even pass them as arguments into `query` and not have them hardcoded inside of `query`? In the second case they wouldn't be part of the cache key at all.

Comment: Fair question - the problem is we still need to pass all the parameters to the API in order for the request to validate... it's just that the API then ignores the value of said parameters once it has validated the request.

Comment: Oh sorry just re-read your comment, I see what you're saying... maybe that could work, certainly a novel approach.... !

Comment: If you don't really care for the first result at all, you could also combine both endpoints into one using a `queryFn` instead of `query`.